# How to authenticate EWS client application (not using EWS Managed API) by using OAuth

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS Soap services from my application to do various outlook exchange operations. This is not using EWS Managed API. This works well.

Now, I am trying to add support of Exchange online with my existing application and trying to authenticate using OAuth. I got below sample to authenticate ews application by using OAuth but that is using EWS Managed API. I am not getting similar example for EWS client application. Can you please suggest how we can do that and if you can point to some example like below then it would be great help.

*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth*

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If its a pure SOAP application then all you need to do is change whatever code your using to include the Bearer Authentication header eg given Microsoft's EWS client sample on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-client-applications

You would change

```
 getFolderRequest.Credentials = userCredentials;
```

by removing this line and then add something that adds the Bearer Header eg

```
getFolderRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
getFolderRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
```

How you obtain the AccessToken in the first place is up to you most people would use the MSAL library eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token?tabs=dotnet